# coffee script method is not defined

Tags: coffeescript

i have coffee script class that defined a method named 'isOutdated', right it only output some text,  i need to use this method in another method, but it always complained 'isOutdated is not defined', don't know why,

here is my code:

```
class A
  ...
  isOutdated: (last, curr) ->
    'hell..o'

  run: (callback) ->
    @store.findOne config, {name : 'a' }, {}, {}, (err, results) =>
      return callback err, null if err
      callback null, isOutdated 'last', 'curr'
```

and here is what it complaint:
[ReferenceError: isOutdated is not defined]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference the `isOutdated` method then you need to say

```
  callback null, @isOutdated 'last', 'curr'
  # -------------^
```

Just `isOutdated` is looking for a local variable, not the method.